# Rails 5 scopes and arrays of enums

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, named-scope

I'm trying to build a subset of my users using scopes.

```
enum role: [ :client, :vendor, :agent, :accounting, :admin ]
scope :staff, -> { where(role: [:agent, :accounting, :admin]) }
```

It works fine for selecting the list (User.staff.all works), but I'd really like the "?" ability to easily check - right now I've hacked it together using

```
<% if (current_user.admin? || current_user.agent? || current_user.accounting?) %>
```

Surely there has to be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following method in the User model

```
def staff?
  User.staff.where(id: self.id).present?
end
```